# Get number of times in loop over Hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, loops, iterator

I have an object of type Hash that I want to loop over via `hash.each do |key, value|`.  I would like to get the number of times I've been through the loop starting at 1.

Is there a method similar to `each` that provides this (while still providing the hash key/value data), or do I need to create another counter variable to increment within the loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `each_with_index` instead of `each`. Note: the index does start at 0:

```
hash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|
```